# flexbox circles and squares using html and css

Tags: html

How can I make this using flexbox with html and css only? Having a hard time using flexbox the correct way.

https://gyazo.com/36d72b75c2c69e6f57122c9da7aa2313

and to make it responsive what would I change in mediaqueries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why flexbox? That looks more like a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Just use display: flex property.

For media queries you can add flex-direction: column on the 'row' class to make it column. By default it is "flex-direction: row" so you do not have to write it.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.row p {
padding: 20px 30px;
background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/08/20/39/boats-7309850_960_720.jpg" class="circle">
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/03/22/00/cat-7300029_960_720.jpg" class="circle">
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks I understand flexbox now but I want to use images as circles or  use images inside those circles and also add the square under them with a text.

Comment: @danceandchance I have edited for you that code. You can use <img> tag instead of <div> and make the images border-radius: 50% property. Also I have added for <p> elements bacgkround with paddings around.